# two calls to timer_settime produce an error

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, posix

I define and I call the function initialize_timer twice from main.
The success or failure depends on the order in which I call this same function twice.
That is, when i call timer_settime, from initialize_timer, it return with 0 the first time. Then, the second time around, it return -1.

So to reiterate: if I call the function initialize_timer twice, the call to the function timer_settime returns with an error 1 .
If I simply reverse the order of the two calls (see main below), then it returns with no error (0 as return value).

Since all the variables in the function initialize_timer are local variable, I guess that the error is in the way i call calloc in main.

Can someone tell me please what the bug is?

Why does the second call to the function timer_setttime fails in my initialize_timer function?

Thanks in advance.

```
void initialize_timer(timer_t * tid, int seconds)
{    
    struct itimerspec * ts;
    struct sigaction *  sa;
    struct sigevent *  sev;
    ts = malloc(sizeof(struct itimerspec));
    sa = malloc(sizeof(struct sigaction));
    sev = malloc(sizeof(struct sigevent));
    if (tid == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr,"malloc");

        /* Establish handler for notification signal */

    sa->sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    if(seconds == 2){
        sa->sa_sigaction = producer;
        printf("producer was created\n");
    }
    if(seconds == 6){
        sa->sa_sigaction = consumer;
        printf("consumer was created\n");
    }
    sigemptyset(&sa->sa_mask);
    if (sigaction(TIMER_SIG, sa, NULL) == -1)
        fprintf(stderr,"sigaction");

    /* Create and start one timer for each command-line argument */

    sev->sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;    /* Notify via signal */
    sev->sigev_signo = TIMER_SIG;        /* Notify using this signal */

    itimerspec( ts, seconds);

    sev->sigev_value.sival_ptr = &tid;
    /* Allows handler to get ID of this timer */

    if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, sev, tid) == -1)
        fprintf(stderr,"timer_create");

    int error=timer_settime(tid, 0, ts, NULL) == -1;
    if (error!=0)
        fprintf(stderr,"error timer_settime");

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t t1, t2;
    int s = 0;
    timer_t *tidlist;
    tidlist = calloc(2, sizeof(timer_t));
    if (tidlist == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc");

    create_threads(&t1, &t2);

    initialize_timer(tidlist + 1, 6); //initilize timer for consumer
    initialize_timer(tidlist, 2); //initilize timer for producer

    s = pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    if (s != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_join");
    s = pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    if (s != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_join");

    printf("glob = %d\n", glob);
    return 1;
}


void itimerspec(struct itimerspec *tsp, int seconds){
    tsp->it_value.tv_sec = seconds;
    tsp->it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    tsp->it_interval.tv_sec = seconds;
    tsp->it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
}
```

Comment: You might like to replace the calls to `fprintf(stderr, <error message)`by `perror(<error message>)` to received more detailed information on the cause of the failure.

Comment: Also the code of `itimerspec()` seems to be relevant.

Comment: also `if(tid == NULL) fprintf(stderr, "malloc")` seems not right in `initializer_timer`, because tid is given from outside. You should check every malloc for `ts`, `sa` and `sev`.

Comment: Are you aware that you can install only one signal handler for the same signal (only last one will be valid)? And what's `TIMER_SIG`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there are two mistakes:

1. You are calling `sigaction` twice in the same thread (main thread). It means you will only install one signal handler (last one).
2. You are giving timer_settime as first parameters a `timer_t *` (a pointer) not `timer_t`. You should enable warnings in your compilator.
   Even if you were giving not `tid`, but `*tid` you would give it the same value in both cases, because your `tidlist` was created by `calloc`, so `tidlist[0] == tidlist[1] == 0`.

Comment: tidlist[0]==tidlist[1]==0 but later, in initialize timer, i do: timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, sev, tid) so it initialized the tidlist[0] or tidlist[1] depending of what i pass to the function.
So I'm not sure if you're correct on the second point. 
But the first point (and you remark on top) was what made my code work. thanks very much

Comment: i didnt have the time to edit my comment.
no you are right for the second point also. It was the critical mistake not to de-reference tid in settime. But why is gcc not complaining? I compiled the code with the -Wall flag

Comment: That seems strange, you would probably have to check definition of timer_t.